# How to compile 64-bit file linking with 32-bit library

Tags: linux, 64-bit, 32-bit

My system is Centos 5.8 64-bit, and I want to compile a file linking with 32-bit library. I add -m32 while compiling, but the result shows "i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `gc_basic_call_model_voice_video_3g_cnf_nbup.o' is incompatible with i386 output".
It seems that the file can't be compiled on 32-bit. But if I don't add -m32, the library can't be compiled. How to compile the file successfully, thanks!

Comment: have you used the flags `-fPIC` and `-rdynamic`

Comment: I use the command "gcc -m32 A.c B.c -Ldir -o output1.o output2.o". But the results shows i386:x86-64 architecture of input file 'output1.o' is incompatible with i386 output. The file in dir is 32-bit library. I don't know how to do :(

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the `-o` option.  When you write `-o output1.o output2.o`, you're telling GCC that the finished executable should be stored in `output1.o`, and `output2.o` is just another *input* file.  GCC doesn't produce intermediate object files when you're not using the `-c` option.  Your `-o` should be the name of the final linked executable.

Answer (score 8):

You can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in the same program.  The compiler is telling you that one of your `.o` files is compiled as a 64-bit object, so it can't be linked into a 32-bit executable.  You'll need to recompile that object file, and probably others as well, from source code using `-m32` for everything.

Comment: Or maybe you're bringing in a 64-bit library (instead of a 64-bit object).  In any case: you *cannot* mix'n'match 32- and 64-bit code.  You must recompile all your .c source, and set your -L library path flags, to insure you're picking up *only* 32-bit files.

Comment: @paulsm4, that's a possibility in general, but in this case the error message specifically says it's an object file.

Answer (score -1):

suppose you compiled a 32 bit version of your program (let's call it foo.c ) in the following manner :

```
gcc -m32 -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

You should then call the linker on it using the -melf_i386 flag.

```
ld <whatever commands / flags you gave earlier> -melf_i386
```

Example :

```
ld -o foo.bin --oformat binary basic.o -melf_i386
```